# iOS7 Safari Mobile| Html video streaming | ended event not triggered

Tags: javascript, html, events, video, ios7

I developed a HTML page for the iPad with an embedded video stream. 
Before I updated my iPad to iOS7, all events worked.
But now, the `ended` event is not triggered anymore in Safari on iOS7. 
Instead I get a "could not load movie" error at the end of the stream in an alert dialog.

Are there any other developers who have encountered this issue? I can't find a solution that works well.

HTML of Video Element:

```
 <video id="de_videoPlayer" preload='auto' src'.....'></video>
```

JavaScript using jQuery:

```
 videoElement = $('video').get(0);
 $(videoElement).on('ended', function() { 
        videoEnded();
        console.log("videoElement event: ended") });
 });
```

Comment: Try another browser to see if it's a Safari specific issue.

Comment: we use apple streaming, the video playback works only on apple devices. on ios6.x it works and in safari on Mac OSX, too.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Please update if you have any workaround.

Answer (score 0):

did you foud a work around ? I searched in apple docs and there seem to be only error callback it works but it is to generic.... i did't suceed to get the specific type of error ...